# Why does ASP.Net bundling include multiple versions of matching files? Can I stop this?

Tags: asp.net, bundling-and-minification

When I bundle a script like so:

```
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/Product/Details").Include(
        "~/Scripts/external/XXXXConfig-{version}.js",
        "~/Scripts/external/Views/Product/ProductFavorite-{version}.js"));
```

My expectation is that if there were two files in that directory:

1. XXXXConfig-1.0.0.js
2. XXXXConfig-1.0.1.js

That it would only include the latest version, i.e., XXXXConfig-1.0.1.js. Instead it is bundling BOTH together, which causes the system to fail spectacularly.

My expectation comes from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification#using-the--wildcard-character-to-select-files), and other sources. Is this expectation wrong? In any case, is there some way to make it so that it ONLY includes the latest version?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your expectation is incorrect. The `{version}` wildcard is used as a placeholder for any version, not the latest. It allows it to update your NuGet package without having to change your bundling code every time.

The only smart thing that the `{version}` wildcard does is that it select the file with `min` (if it exists) for release and with no `min` for debug. Other than that, it's just a wildcard like any other.

I'm not aware of any built-in feature that selects the latest release for you. You'll have to program it by yourself if you want that. You can search to see if someone has already done such a thing. But I wonder why you want more than one version to exist in your folder.

**Edit:** To elaborate on the `min` feature as your requested, I think the [MSDN that you linked to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification#using-bundling-and-minification-with-aspnet-web-forms-and-web-pages) described well, but here is an example:

Let say your folder has two files SEMSConfig-1.0.0.js and SEMSConfig-1.0.0.min.js. When you run your project in debug mode, the file SEMSConfig-1.0.0.js will be used. When you run your project in release mode (or publish it), the file SEMSConfig-1.0.0.min.js will be used.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "min" approach?

Comment: But it would minify both XXXConfig-1.0.0.js and XXXConfig-1.0.1.js, would it not?

Comment: Most likely yes.

Comment: see more here - https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/include-jquery-library-in-a-view-or-page-in-different-ways/ - on the "min" - that article also unfortunately speaks about "using latest version from folder" which is wrong, seems to include all it finds, which is a problem if you set WebPublish for example to not remove old files